# Is it possible to have two SPI controllers and one SPI peripheral?

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, sd, raspberry-pi-pico

I have one Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+ and one Raspberry Pi Pico. I want to allow both of these devices to write and read data from this SD card reader: https://www.adafruit.com/product/254

How should I make the connections in this regard, so that both the Raspberry Pi A+ and Raspberry Pi Pico acts as a master for the SD card reader and can read and write data to it? How would the connections in terms of wiring look like (for CLK, MISO, MOSI and CS)?

Comment: You need some kind of arbitration between both masters. This is sometimes harder than it seems. What is typically much safer is to change the architecture by having another, independant communication channel between both masters, and having only one of those directly communicating with the slave (let's call it the "primary" master). When the other (let's call it the "secondary" master) wants to communicate with the slave, it asks the "primary" master to do it on its behalf. Note:  this architecture also often simplify other, unrelated problems because it better separate concerns.

Comment: Not commenting on the wiring, but the two rpis will have to synchronize to avoid concurrent access, both in terms of SPI coms and filesystem modifications. Does your application preclude having a single rpi access the sd card and write data on behalf of the other?

Comment: It can do a setup where, the rpi pico can communicate through another spi or i2c to requesting read and write access to the sd card. But the problem with this middleware approach is that, the pi pico will loose critical clock cycles trying to look for calls from the pi a+ and executing them. That is why, both the pi pico and pi a+ needs independent access to the sd card.

Comment: They will have to talk to each other all the time anyways to make sure that they are not writing data at the same time.

Comment: @DamienD is it possible to achieve this type of communication through static memory flags and somehow the raspberry pi a+ able to access the pi pico memory addresses through i2c? Some sort of direct memory access.

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing this seems like doing it the hard way.  set up one pi as a file server and connect the SD card to that device.

Comment: How do I interface these 3 devices, considering I have a way of having non blocked access to the SD card from both the devices. I mean, each device will be aware of when the other one is access the sd card. I think I know, how I can implement this in software and yeah I will burn up some clock cycles doing this but I will implement this logic in the 2nd core of the pi pico. So, after this how should the hardware connections might look like for this type of setup? And what type of SPI modes or configuration I should use?

Comment: You would need to make sure the inactive master keeps its SPI output pins high impedance to let the other one drive the shared lines. Then design a way to avoid access conflicts at the SPI level (not necessarily hard but not trivial either). Then design a way to avoid filesystem corruption (not trivial either, probably hard).

Answer (score 2):

Since the file systems used on flash cards do not support concurrent block-level access by two systems and assuming you've worked out how to deal with that, it should work provided you gate the SPI lines correctly (eg connect them in parallel and turn only one on at a time)